# Using explode after using str_replace PHP

Tags: php, str-replace, explode

I have a very simple code which replaces specific values in a string and then explodes it.

But i need to do a count on the string after exploding, Here is my example

```
$exclude=array();
$exclude[0]="with";
$exclude[1]="on";

$search_string="Boy with a t-shirt walking on the road";
echo str_word_count($search_string);  

//the str_replace is suppose to remove the word "with" and "on" from string
// count search string before explode

$sch2 = str_replace($exclude,"", trim($search_string));
$sch=explode(" ",trim($sch2));
echo count($sch);  


//count search string after explode

//The result of the second count after exploding is suppose to be 6 and NOT 8
```

But when i count the $sch string after exploding, it gives me 8

It seems like there is something am doing wrong, any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: try doing `var_dump($sch);` - perhaps $sch doesn't contain what you think it does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace 'with' with nothing, then you still got two spaces. So the split will still return 8 items, one of which is an empty string where the word 'with' used to be.

To solve this, you might replace `'with '` (including space`, so you actually replace one of the two spaces as well. But I don't know if that would work in your actual production code, of course.

You could also use `[array_filter][1]` to filter out the empty value, like this:

```
$sch2 = str_replace($exclude,"", trim($search_string));
$sch = explode(" ",trim($sch2));
$sch = array_filter($sch);
echo count($sch);
```

Or even:

```
// To prevent 'false positives' due to PHP's default weak comparison.
$sch = array_filter($sch, function($a){return $a !== '';});
```

Comment: Good catch - adding a leading and trailing space to the strings in exclude, then replacing with a single space, would give the expected result.

Comment: I think you mean two of which are empty strings.

Comment: `str_replace("  ", " ", str_replace($exclude,"", trim($search_string)))` Replace any double-spaces with just one space. Then continue as-is. @html-tosin

Comment: @Anonymous Ah, yeah. `on` is replaced as well, so you got actually two sequences of two spaces, each resulting in an empty string in the expoded string.

Comment: I just used var_dump now, and discovered that what u are saying is VERY TRUE

Comment: @PatrickQ That will work in this case, but it may fail in an unpredictiable way when the original string contained two sequential spaces as well, or when the replaced words are adjacent, resulting in three sequential spaces.

Comment: @HtmlTosin Like, I said in my answer, you can include the space in the word to replace. That way, you'll replace the word and the space after or before) it. You could also try PatrickQ's suggestion. Both will work in your example, but either might fail in some real life situations, depending on what the exact rules are in case of extremes (for instance: word at the end of a string).

Comment: Yes @GolezTrol, for example "moving on with my car" also could be the string, so is there any way around it ?

Comment: @GolezTrol True. Although most solutions would probably include a certain level of assumption based on an "expected" input format. For instance, the example you mentioned in the answer wouldn't work if the word being replaced was at the end of the line.

Comment: @PatrickQ Exactly. I'm certainly not saying your suggestion is wrong. Just pointing out that either one has its drawbacks, which is fine as long as you are aware of them.

Comment: Would the downvoter be so kind as to explain what is so 'not useful' about my answer so I might improve it?

Comment: @GolezTrol, thanks for your answer, it actually worked...am just looking for a better way around it, such as when more complicated words are contained in a string

Comment: @HtmlTosin Please review my addition about `array_filter` of just now. I think it will solve your problem in a more flexible and reliable fashion, although it might also filter out values of `'0'` for instance. You could specify a callback function to compare using strict operators, though.

Comment: Although when i Looped the array, to display the elements of the array, It gave me "Notice: Undefined offset:" Error. I just tried that now, any particular reason